# ASP.NET MVC5 Displaying String in a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial view, which I am passing a model of type `WebSite.Models.ManageModel` which is simply

```
public class ManageModel
{
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public ManageUserViewModel ManageUserViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

I want to access the email address and place it into a `TextBox` in my partial view. So in that partial view I have

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ManageUserViewModel.EmailAddress, 
            new 
            { 
                @class = "col-md-10 form-control", 
                @type = "text",
                @placeholder = "Email Address",
                @value = Model.UserEmailAddress
             })
    </div>
</div>
<span class="label label-danger">@Model.UserEmailAddress</span>
```

Now, the email address correctly displays in the `label label-danger` but not in my `TexBox`. What is wrong with this code?

[image: State]

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. The action that launches the `Manage` view (which contains my partial views) is

```
// GET: /Account/Manage.
public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage =
        message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? 
            "Your password has been changed": 
        message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? 
            "Your password has been set" : 
        message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? 
            "The external login was removed" : 
        message == ManageMessageId.ChangeEmailAddressSuccess ?
            "Your email address was successfully updated" :
        message == ManageMessageId.Error ? 
            "An error has occurred." : "";
    ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");

    // Not passing the model to the view, because I am 
    // unsure how to retrieve the information.
    return View(); 
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to retrieve the users data. My `ManageUserViewModel` is

```
public class ManageUserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage =
        "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage =
        "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can get the `ApplicationUser` data via `var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());` but this is the default plus my added `EmailAddress` field, so it does not contain the password information. What should I be doing in this case?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your TextBoxFor should be `TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmailAddress...`

Comment: I had something similar if i remember correctly. Try capital case the v in value. @Value = Model.UserEmailAddress

Comment: FYI, if you are actually able to retrieve a user's password, you're *doing something wrong*. Do a Google search for password hashing and how to store passwords properly.

Comment: Thanks @Ic. I am hashing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can override the value like that without writing your own `TextBoxFor` extension method. I believe the framework is simply ignoring your `@value`. Furthermore it seems like your design pattern is a little off, and you have somewhat of a hybrid model where the same information is in two different places.

Try populating your view model (`ManageUserViewModel.EmailAddress`) with the value you want displayed. Obviously I don't know what you're trying to do, but I don't understand the purpose of the nested view model and the `UserEmailAddress` property.

Comment: And there is no point in `@type = "text"` since `TextBoxFor()` renders it anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke Agreed, although not sure why, but I wondered if the OP is again trying to override a `type=email` if there's an attribute attached, so I left it alone.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. I will look to use `ManageUserViewModel` to get the email, but at the moment I am just playing about trying to learn ASP.NET/MVC. @StephenMuecke how can I populate the text box with the required value if I can't do it as I have attempted?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor()` will always render `type="text"`. Its only `@Html.EditorFor()` that will consider the datatype attributes and render `email`, `date` etc

Comment: The whole purpose of using the strongly typed helpers is to ensure you properties are correctly bound which is why it always renders the `name` and `value` attributes based on the model properties. You can use `@TextBox("ManageUserViewModel.EmailAddress", Model.UserEmailAddress, new {...` but I do not recommend it. Just set the value of `ManageUserViewModel.EmailAddress` to the value of `UserEmailAddress` in the controller before you pass the view. Your using MVC, make use of its features!

Comment: @StephenMuecke really appreciate your advice here. I have updated the question slightly. I would like to use your answer above, so I have removed the custom ViewModel I had and am attempting to use the `ManageUserViewModel` directly. However, I don't know how to get this data for the current user. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's actually @lc.'s answer, but happy to help. Why do you need the password? Typically you would pass an instance of `ManageUserViewModel` (with only the `EmailAddress` property assigned) to the view, then when the user posts back, pass the email, old password and new password values to a method that returns a value indicating success.

Comment: So If you want the email field to be filled in then `ManageUserViewModel model = new ManageUserViewModel(); model.EmailAddress = "..."; return View(model);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke RE `TextBoxFor()` vs `EditorFor()`: Yes, you are absolutely right. Apologies for my lack of coffee :)